# SSRS Rendering Issues

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

We have an issue with a few of our reports where they don't properly render the far right hand side of the page the first time they are generated but will always properly render if you then refresh, or if you export to another medium (pdf, excel).

For example, the first time I render one of our reports the far right hand side cuts off, like so:

[image]

After I refresh the page, it then renders correctly:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this and what I could do to resolve it? I've tried re-setting my page dimensions and even rebuilding tablix controls but nothing has worked - I'm at a loss.

Comment: Check this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/97185ce3-87c5-4f5a-a6df-5b89118ae9fa

Comment: @praveen My problem is a long offshoot from that (note: completely unrelated as this isn't a sizing issue) but I'll take a look at the suggestions there and try them out

Comment: @Michael, What browser/version is affected? Just in case it's IE 8, check this page. It suggests to set AsyncRendering="true" in the Report Viewer control.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqlreportingservices/thread/bffa2c8f-dc88-410c-a268-f3e33e0405f2

Comment: @dev_etter Looks like that's it! Could you post as an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Comment: @Michael, can you also confirm that this was IE 8? (to be thorough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE 8, check this page. It suggests to set AsyncRendering="true" in the Report Viewer control.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqlreportingservices/thread/bffa2c8f-dc88-410c-a268-f3e33e0405f2

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, but my problem turned out to be Lync. If you have Lync, it adds a little extra icon after phone numbers.

This does not show up when you're making the report, and does not show up when the report first opens. It only pops in when you mouse over the report. My tables look fine until I mouse over, and then the far right column gets cut off as it gets moved over.

Comment: Good addition but this question is quite outdated so I won't change the answer (as the original did satisfy the requirements). Hopefully somebody gets some need out of those so upvoted.